# Which company to roll 401k over to

Tags: united-states, 401k

Should I roll over my 401k with existing company JPmorgan or swith company to Ameriprise financial. My husbands mutual fund is with ameriprise financial . is it better to have money with two different companies or the same. Is fees different

Comment: Is it a question **?**

Comment: Are you rolling your 401(k) into another 401(k) or into an IRA? If IRA, then you have many more companies to choose from.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are three important considerations:

- Fees - Which company offers the funds you want for the lowest fees?
- Selection - Which company offers a greater variety of funds that you are interested in?
- Account Management - If you kept your money with just one company, would it be easier for you interact with your accounts? More accounts/companies can equal greater complexity.

Comment: Also if you are rolling a 401K to an Ira, you have a lot of other options in good reliable low cost, no-load companies. Vanguard, Fidelity, T. Row Price, just to name a few.  So I'd apply those considerations to a variety of choices and see which one looks best to you.  No need to limit it to just the two you indicated.

Comment: Yeah - consider more alternatives than just those two. Also, pretty much *everyone* loves Vanguard, except perhaps their competitors and the do-it-yourself "playing the market is fun! investment research is my hobby!" crowd.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are talking about rolling a 401k over to an IRA since if you were rolling over to another 401k you probably would not have a choice as to where it would be.

Ameriprise will generally have lower fees than JPMorgan. (Probably why your husband's mutual fund is with Ameriprise.)

Additionally having both accounts with Ameriprise will better allow them to assist you with your long term financial planning.

For these two reasons I would recommend rolling your account over to Ameriprise.

*No, I do not work for Ameriprise*